# How to resolve this sqlite issue with my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

I just deployed my app to production on heroku. However, now when I try to switch back to development and run rails c on my command prompt, I get the following error:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/database
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler.rb:133:in `require'
        from D:/Railstutorials/Taxibol/Platform/iteration2/taxibol_operator/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:146:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:146:in `require_application_and_environment!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Following is my database.yml file:

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  adapter: postgresql  
  host: ec2-23-23-210-37.compute-1.amazonaws.com
  port: 5432
  database: d9qgibt6qabecr  
  username: ygaayqvpdrfjwa
  password: 'my_password'
```

I am facing the same issue when I want to start my server in dev mode. Where could I be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend installing Postgres locally so that your development and production environments are the same.

Sometimes when troubleshooting, it's helpful to run your production environment locally because there might be some other settings which you may not notice which are different in production vs. development.  Running production locally is the fast way to test that, and for that you'd need Postgres installed locally because that's what you set in database.yml.

This is how to run your production server or production console locally from the terminal:
RAILS_ENV=production rails server
or
RAILS_ENV=production rails console

FYI, a great way for Mac users to install Postgres is with http://postgresapp.com/ because it's easy to get running with CMD+SPACE_BAR (system search using Spotlight) and typing in "postgres".

Answer (score 0):

ran rake db:create and it worked. Though I don't know why. Would be great if someone could explain...

Comment: The actual sqlite file wasn't created, so it couldn't connect to it. When you ran `rake db:create` it generated the file.